# pop up on hover to img

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i'm studying wp7 app changing app on https://github.com/slodge/face. I want to change this app so that this app could show all attribtes in pop up window, when i point to particular face, like on http://developers.face.com/tools/#faces/detect. I have all attributes returned in JSON.
[image]
II have no idea how to do that. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You want to display a popup on hover on a phone? You do realize that Windows Phone (and no other smartphone AFAIK) implements hover detection right?

Comment: no ,actually i\m not strong in wp7 app, and i don't realize it. What whould you suggest to solve this kind of problem? something kinda pic above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no hover event on the phone, the best you can do is to display the popup when the user taps on the image. I'd do the following:

1. Use a [WrapPanel](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth) to display the image grid
2. Add a Tap event handler to each image
3. Style a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in XAML to look like your example, have it closed initially
4. Bind the values to be displayed Popup to some class you create that contains all the fields to be displayed
5. When the user taps on an image fetch all the attributes for that image (using [JSON.net](https://json.codeplex.com/) for example) and set the properties of the class you've data bound to the Popup
6. Position the Popup appropriately using the `VerticalOffset` and `HorizontalOffset` properties
7. Display the Popup by setting the `IsOpen` property

Instead of using `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup` you could use the Popup control available in the [coding4fun toolkit](https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) since the latter is hardware accelerated unlike the former.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Wrap panel or a Canvas to populate the data.
Use Visibility to visible and collapse to show hide the popup.